# After Windows 10 update 1803, network fails randomly

Tags: windows, networking, connection, update

We have a network with 4 servers and several clients with W10.

The server's OS versions are:

- W10 Enterprise: 10.0.17134.137
- W10 Pro: 10.0.17134.165
- W10 Enterprise: 10.0.17134.165
- W10 Pro: 10.0.17134.165

After the update, wich took place by the end of May, we are experiencing several network issues: Many Client computers are unable to connect with the servers or connect only sometimes. Also, it affects any resource available on the network. May be a printer, another computer with shared folders...etc...

After looking for solutions over the internet, we have not found any way to solve this situation.

An important clue is that IS POSSIBLE to connect using the IP but not the name of the computer in the network. Maybe there is a problem with the DNS?

Comment: Windows 10 is NOT intended for use as a server.

Comment: Actually, the issue affects any resource shared on the network. Even a printer...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution has been to Edit the Hosts archive **adding the names of the machines and its IP's**. The path is something like : C:/Windows/System32/Drivers/etc/

Another solution, provided by a Microsoft Technician, is to uncheck the IPv6 option in the properties of the network connection.

Both of them work fine.

Answer (score 3):

**You can't create a server with client versions of Windows and hope it works properly…**

However, in Windows 10, since 1709, the SMB1 client is not installed by default and it's probably the source of your problems. You should connect to the file share via the FQDN, and with a supported protocol, like SMB2 or SMB3.

More informations here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4034314/smbv1-is-not-installed-by-default-in-windows